# Rails form select box with class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two types of select boxes in  rails form:

```
<%= f.select :result, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

it works nice - using added class, and second one:

```
<%= f.select :test_id, class: 'form-control' do %>
   <%= @tests.each do |t| -%>
      <%= content_tag(:option, t.topic, value: t.id) %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

which doesn't use 'form-control'. Any ideas how to add this class correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML options are for the 3rd argument as it shows on your first code sample example. So you must insert an empty hash in between the first and second argument.

Try :

```
f.select :test_id, {}, class: 'form-control' do
```

Comment: Great! Had to add two empty hashes and it worked correctly! Thank you!